# SUM(cost) of data in table based on another table dates

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

how to sum categories of table 1 between each 2 date rows in table 2
[Excel Table 1, 2 and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ7ty.png)

i tried something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(cost) FROM table1 WHERE date
BETWEEN 
(SELECT date FROM table2 WHERE (line 2,3,4)) 
AND 
(SELECT date FROM table2 WHERE (line 1,2,3)) 
GROUP BY category
```

but the problem is it gives me only result between 2 & 1 or between 3 & 2 or 4 & 3 but cant get them all in one code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$date_1 = mysqli_query($main_link, "SELECT date FROM table2 ORDER BY id DESC");
$date_2 = mysqli_query($main_link, "SELECT date FROM table2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 12 OFFSET 1");
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($date_1)){
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($date_2)){
    $date_1st = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$row1['date']} -1 day"));
    $date_2nd = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$row2['date']}"));
    $query = mysqli_query($main_link, "SELECT category, SUM(cost) FROM table1 WHERE date BETWEEN '$date_2nd' AND '$date_1st'");

    while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "{$row3['category']} : {$row3['SUM(cost)']}<br><br>";
    }

    echo"<hr>";
    break;
}
}
?>
```